# Parameter name ommited

Tags: c, keyword

Здравствуйте! Есть функция:

```
#include <math.h>
...
void mat4x4_projection(mat4x4 m, const float fov, const float aspect, const float n, const float f) {
    mat4x4_identity(m);
    const float ctg_half_fov = 1.0f/tanf(fov/2);

    m[0][0] = ctg_half_fov/aspect;
    m[1][1] = ctg_half_fov;
    m[2][2] = (f+n)/(f-n);
    m[3][2] = (-2.0f*f*n)/(f-n);
    m[2][3] = 1.0f;
    m[3][3] = 0.0f;
}
```

Если заменить имена параметров `f` и `n` на `far` и `near` соответственно, то компилятор выдает ошибку: `Parameter name ommited`.

Слова `far` и `near` не значатся как ключевые (смотрел на http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword).

Собственно вопрос, с чем может быть связана эта ошибка?

```
Win 10 x64
gcc 4.8.1
```

Comment: Укажите ваши ОС, компилятор и их версии. У меня не воспроизводится на Linux ни в GCC, ни в Clang.

Comment: @Ainar-G, обновил вопрос.

Comment: @0andriy Думаю, вы можете отправить эту ссылку с цитатой из неё в качестве ответа.

Comment: @0andriy, нет, в проекте точно их нет. Значит, все-таки, в заголовках Windows.

Comment: Тысячу лет назад, когда ещё только-только появились писюки с процессором 286, MS выпустила С-компилятор (насколько я помню, V6), в котором присутствовали ключевые слова  *far* и *near*.  Они говорили компилятору, где расположен данный объект - в пределах 64К адресного пространства, или далее. Сдаётся мне, что это как раз об этом...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давным давно, когда компьютеры были 8- и 16-битными, а 32-битные только-только появлялись, в среде DOS и Windows были специальные аннотации к указателям (чаще речь шла про указатели на функции), говорящие о том, нужно ли применять сегментные регистры для адресации. Так, `far` отвечала, что указатель лежит за пределами текущего сегмента кода, когда `near` указывала на то, что адрес расположен внутри текущего сегмента кода.

Для поддержки такого наследия некоторые компиляторы всё ещё содержат эти аннотации. Именно поэтому у вас возникает ошибка.

Более подробно суть проблемы изложена [здесь](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2144/) по отношению к среде Windows и компилятору MinGW.